# C3p0 trying to create a new connection pool and failing with ClassNotFoundException

Tags: spring, hibernate, connection-pooling, c3p0

I'm seeing a very strange behavior in my application.

My application setup: Spring + Hibernate + C3p0

Application keeps running fine, when all of a sudden I start seeing these errors in logs and system totally stop processing any database specific requests.

```
WARN c3p0.C3P0Registry - Could not create for find ConnectionCustomizer with class name ''.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry.getConnectionCustomizer(C3P0Registry.java:181)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.getConnectionCustomizer(C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.java:636)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.createPooledConnectionPool(C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.java:738)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.getPool(C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.java:257)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.getPool(C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.java:271)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:80)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:423)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:144)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareSelectStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:123)
at org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator.generate(SequenceGenerator.java:73)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:99)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:187)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:172)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:94)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:70)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:507)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:499)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:495)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$18.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:690)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.execute(HibernateTemplate.java:365)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate(HibernateTemplate.java:687)
```

- Why would C3p0 require to create a new connection pool at this
  particular time, before these exceptions application is 100% working
  fine and responding perfectly.
- Also I've not provided any connectionCustomizerClassName property in
  my c3p0 configurations, why would it load one? in this stack trace I
  see it's not-null empty string ''.

Any clues?

==============================================================================
Following hibernate jars I see in application's classpath:

- hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar
- spring-hibernate-1.2.6.jar

Following c3p0 jars I see in application's classpath:

- c3p0-0.9.1.jar
- c3p0-0.9.2-pre5.jar
- c3p0-oracle-thin-extras-0.9.2-pre5.jar

Code that manually read these properties and set on datasource (I do not read/set any connectionCustomizerClassName property here at all)

```
ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
dataSource.setMinPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty("jdbc.hibernate.c3p0.minPoolSize")));
.....
```

Here are C3p0 properties being used:

```
jdbc.hibernate.c3p0.minPoolSize=100
jdbc.hibernate.c3p0.initialPoolSize=100
jdbc.hibernate.c3p0.maxPoolSize=1000
jdbc.hibernate.c3p0.maxIdleTime=21600
jdbc.hibernate.c3p0.maxStatementsPerConnection=0
jdbc.hibernate.c3p0.maxStatements=0
jdbc.hibernate.c3p0.numHelperThreads=30
jdbc.hibernate.c3p0.checkoutTimeout=30000
jdbc.hibernate.c3p0.idleConnectionTestPeriod=900
jdbc.hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery=SELECT 1 FROM dual
jdbc.hibernate.c3p0.maxConnectionAge=0
jdbc.hibernate.c3p0.maxIdleTimeExcessConnections=3600
jdbc.hibernate.c3p0.acquireIncrement=10
jdbc.hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryDelay=5000
jdbc.hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts=6
jdbc.hibernate.c3p0.propertyCycle=180
```

Comment: Post some configuration and/or relevant classes.

Comment: By any chance are you using *multi-tenancy* features of Hibernate? And what are your versions of Hibernate and C3P0?

Comment: somewhere -- in c3p0.properties, system properties, c3p0-config.xml, hibernate or spring config files, JMX, etc, you must have a connectionCustomizerClassName getting set to an empty string. perhaps c3p0 should guard against that case, and treat an empty string as null. but that's what's happening. c3p0 pools get recreated whenever their DataSource's config properties are altered. also a new pool is created for every new set of authentication credentials. either of those might be triggering pool creation.

Comment: I've updated the question with hibernate+c3p0 jars I see in classpath.

Comment: We do not use multi-tenancy features of Hibernate.

Comment: @SteveWaldman Can you please explain "3p0 pools get recreated whenever their DataSource's config properties are altered"? Can an automatic event trigger this change? Also as far as I have seen C3p0 code C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.getPool(C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.java:271) is a non parameterized call to obtain the pool with default credentials. Application is not passing any new username/password combination in this case to obtain a connection.

Comment: c3p0 DataSources are JavaBeans. construction of a new pool (and the problem you see above) would be triggered by someone calling dataSource.setConnectionCustomizerClassName(""). i doubt any code explicitly does this. but perhaps some JMX tool you are using? (certainly within c3p0, there is no "event" that triggers config changes. within your larger app, i don't know.) the getPool(...) method is overloaded, including versions with the default auth and others accepting authentication info (i'd need to know your version to check line numbers).

Comment: @SteveWaldman : c3p0-0.9.1.jar as the stack trace match exactly with the class (C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.java) source line number 271 which is: return getPool( defaultAuth );

Comment: @SteveWaldman : We use default jvisualvm as JMX client. I've not checked that if this property is even visible in the JMX client or editable.

Comment: (it should be both visible and editable. so if ppl are accidentally updating the property to a blank string, that would explain what you are seeing.)

Comment: @SteveWaldman : Actually you've nailed it. Can you please post it as an answer so that I may accept it as the right answer. I can see the error if I just select the property in VisualVM and then on focus lost  it triggers the error. Dangerous, so dangerous, will take serious measures now ... C3p0 gets refreshed by any property update,  I see an event in log Initializing C3p0 Pool ... all the time, does this means, it just kills the whole pool and recreates a new one?

Comment: Yes. Internally, the pool's configs are immutable. Any update of pool properties provokes a winding down of an old pool and replacement with a new one. c3p0 should deal OK with (that is, it should ignore) degenerate updates, ie where you set a property to the value it already had. (i'll try to review and double check that.) but in your case, you are setting a parameter that was null to a blank String, so c3p0 considers that a real change. i've added a guard (in the current development series, in github) so all-whitespace connectionCustomizerClassNames are interpreted as nulls, none set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up a conversation in the comments on the posted question, it looks like the issue here is that VisualVM updates the null valued property `connectionCustomizerClassName` to an empty String value, which c3p0 currently treats an non-null and interprets as a class name.

Going forward (c3p0-0.9.5-pre7 and above), c3p0 will guard against this, interpret an all-whitespace `connectionCustomizerClassName` as equivalent to null. But in the meantime or for older versions, take care.

One easy workaround would be to define a NullConnectionCustomizer:

```
package mypkg;

import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.*;

public class NullConnectionCustomizer extends AbstractConnectionCustomizer
{}
```

And then use `mypkg.NullConnectionCustomizer` for `connectionCustomizerClassName`, so that the corresponding field in VisualVM is not empty and ambiguously interpretable as empty String or null.

Comment: Just one more question, I've not checked it myself yet. Does c3p0 data source gets initialized/reset even if any of the new property being set is having the same value as the previous one? Should it not just reconfigure data source if the property value was actually changed at all (comparing the old and new value etc ...)

Comment: Actually you explained this point in your last comment, just wanted to know the results of your 'double-checking the code' :)

Comment: unfortunately, the answer is no, not reliably. resetting a parameter to its same value by JMX will in many cases result in reconstruction of the pool. (i'll work on fixing this!) hopefully there is some protection from this in JMX clients -- ie hopefully they don't routinely reset parameter values that users have not changed -- but c3p0 should guard against this.

Comment: so, this will be fixed as of c3p0-0.9.5-pre7. changes to guard against resetting pools when attributes are reset to their own value are now committed on github. (however, a switch from null to empty string for connectionCustomizerClassName will still provoke a pool reset, harmlessly though, as an empty or whitespace String will now be interpreted like null, no ConnectionCustomizer desired.)